# Can I call a piece of an apple “apple”?

Tags: articles, partitives

Can I just say *apple* without an article instead of *a piece of an apple*? In Korean language, it’s possible.

- There’s apple left.
- There’s a piece of apple left.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I imagine you could answer to *What are you eating?* with *Apple.* even if you are just eating an apple slice, but I would not say you can always replace *a piece of apple* with *apple*. Do you have a specific phrase for the question? Otherwise, the question is too broad, IMO.

Comment: @apaderno I added examples.

Comment: @Community,  the issue has now been addressed,  why haven't you deleted your comment

Comment: @JamesK: That's a bot and the comment is undeletable and unflaggable

Comment: @Void James is so cute.

Comment: @Void if you don't talk to the bot, how will it ever attain consciousness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English has a system of singular and plural, countable and uncountable nouns.

As a countable noun "an apple" means a whole apple.  That is part of the meaning of "an apple".  So a piece of apple is not "an apple"

As an uncountable noun "apple" means the substance that apples are made of.  It would be more natural to say "There's some apple left" The word "some". It determines the noun, and so helps the meaning.

Or it is correct to use a partitive noun like "piece" or "slice"  "There are three slices of apple left".  You need this form if you want to give the number of slices.

Comment: Agreed. "some apple" is the first thing that came to mind.